# Can't Inspect Variables When Debugging .NET Async/Await Functions

Tags: c#, debugging, async-await

I have a .NET 4.5 proj that is using `async/await` functionality.

When i try to inspect/quickwatch a variable reference after an await statement, i get the following:

> `The name 'id' does not exist in the current context`

Know how to fix this so i can debug it?

Edit-- here's the code

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task works_as_expected()
    {
        var repo = Config.Ioc.GetInstance<IAsyncRepository<Customer>>();

        var work = Config.Ioc.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
        Customer c= new Customer()
        {
            FirstName = "__Micah",
            LastName = "__Smith_test",
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            DateModified = DateTime.Now,
            Email = "m@m.com",
            Phone = "7245551212"
        }; 

        var id=await repo.Insert(c);
        // i can't inspect the value of id
        Assert.True(id > 0);
    }
```

Comment: When are you trying to inspect id? Is it truly after the `var id... ` line?

Comment: Indeed it is-- this is something that happens throughout my code everywhere, this is just a very simplified code version where it also happens. I'm hoping that getting an explanation for why it happens in the micro will end up also telling me why it happens in the macro

Comment: This works for me. I created a super dumbed down implementation. `var id = await Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); return 1; });return id;`

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any IL in here (the repo uses an ORM) that may be preventing it...

Comment: I suspect I'm having the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/26502128/1085837
Interesting comment about the IL, my code uses dapper which uses a lot of IL

Answer (score -2):

That variable doesn't exist yet, so there is no way to inspect it's value.  It has no value (yet).

It won't be defined, technically, until you reach the line of code that defines it, and it won't have a value until you initialize it.  While you can technically inspect the value of a variable before it is ever assigned in some cases, that value can never be accessed in code (outside of unsafe code) so there's little reason to look at it.

As for when the memory for that location will be allocated (which is when you first have the option of looking at it in the debugger) that will be after you have reached the first line after the last `await` before the variable is used.