# Visual Studio debugger shows wrong value (null where there should be a value)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm stuck, why does this happen? The code literally says that entity != null but the debugger thinks it's null. What is going on?

[image: visual studio screenshot - debugging]

I already changed to x86, recompiled, cleaned, even restarted the pc. And the code was always like this, there is no version where the if statement was different. And if I continue I don't get a null-pointer exception.

Comment: I don't know why this is happening, but do you get the same error if you refactor your for loop to a Linq query?

Comment: what's the `Immediate Window` say when you check `entity`?

Comment: I've seen this before, do a complete clean of your bin and obj folders

Comment: You could try fully qualifying `entity`

Comment: Perhaps a code optimization issue?  Untick optimize code in Project -> Properties -> Build?

Comment: Even though you mention you switched to x86, [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2011/03/31/misreporting-of-variable-values-when-debugging-x64-code-with-the.aspx) might be something to try - what happens when you insert any assigning line of code between the `if(entity != null){` and `entity.RowVersion =` lines?  e.g. per the link insert something like `bool AnyOldVariableWeDontActuallyUse = true;`

Answer (score 6):

I experienced the same problem when there was variable with same name declared earlier in the method. 
In that case debugger would only 'notice' first variable. It has no impact on actual code execution.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but I think it is an effect of the `foreach` loop in combination with the `ChangeTracker.Entries()` function.

The foreach function is collection some data on demand.
So it is not getting all the data from `ChangeTracker.Entries()` and afterwards starting the loop with each value.

It is more getting the first value from the function --> execution the value --> getting second value --> ...

So the value is null, because you haven't used the object yet.

Change your `ChangeTracker.Entries()` into `ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList()` and I think you will see a change.

Take a look into the `yield` command for an deeper understanding how the iterator function works. (The logic is a bit confusing :) )